# Can Quarkus/CDI ApplicationScoped beans be removed from context or garbage collected at runtime for any reason?

Tags: cdi, quarkus

My understanding is that these beans are simple java objects, but once they have survived being removed at build-time and have been (lazily) initialized, they are held in the context indefinitely and should not be GC-able even if they are idle for long times.

But I was unable to confirm it after running through the [2.0 CDI specs](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#introduction) and the bean lifecycle/CDI related Quarkus docs.

Are there any specific cases where this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in theory, you can do `AlterableContext#destroy(Contextual<?>)` - this would remove the contextual instance (i.e. the instance of your `@ApplicationScoped` bean) from the context, and then it can be garbage-collected if there are no other references.

For example, in quarkus you can do `Arc.container().instance(MyApplicationScopedFoo.class).destroy()`. This would call the `@PreDestroy` callback if present, `@PreDestroy` interceptors if bound, and remove the `MyApplicationScopedFoo` instance from the application context.